# How to get the result 2^100 * 3^3 in modulo 1000000007

Tags: c, modulo

I have a question, how to get a result of (2^100)*(3^5) in modulo 10^9 + 7? The program will ask the user to input the power (2^a) and 3^b, after that, the output will show the result of 2^a * 3^b.

I tried to convert all the big numbers into modulo, and times the modulo. But, it doesnt work for 2*100 * 3^5

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    long long int testcase,b,c,N,a;
    long long int pow2,pow3 = 1;
    long long int m = 1000000007;

    // input the power
    scanf("%lld",&a); getchar();
    scanf("%lld",&b); getchar();

    // power of 2 (2^a)
    for(int i = 1; i <= a; i++){
        pow2 = pow2 * 2;
    }
    // power of 3 (3^b)
    for(int j = 1; j <= b; j++){
        pow3 = pow3 * 3;
    }

    // convert the big numbers into modulo
    long long int i = 1;
    i = (1*pow2) % m ;
    long long int j = 1;
    j = (1*pow3) % m;

    // the result of first modulo times second modulo
    printf("%lld\n", i*j);
    // doesnt work for 2^100 * 3^5

    return 0;
}
```

For a = 2 and b = 5 its gives the output of 972 (which is correct)
for a = 100 and b = 3 its gives 0 output.

Comment: `pow2` is uninitialized. But the bug you're seeing is that `pow2` and `pow3` can overflow when you're computing the powers. Try `pow2 = (pow2 * 2) % m;` and `pow3 = (pow3 * 3) % m`. A third bug is that the result should be `(pow2 * pow3) % m`, and not just `i*j` as you have currently.

Comment: long long int can up to 2^63... with value of 2^100, it will overflow

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that is not actually true.

Comment: You can do modular exponentiation by repeated squaring. The key here is that you can take the modulo `1000000007` from *any intermediate product* any number of times. Thus `2^100 * 3^3 mod 1000000007 == ((2^50 % 1000000007) * (2^50 % 1000000007) * 3 ^ 3) % 1000000007`... for example

Comment: @PaulHankin it works actually thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `pow2` is uninitialized and therefore the behaviour is undefined. If initialized to `1`, then the problem is that 2^100 does not fit in the `long long int`. The best fix is to take the modulo as often as possible.

```
// power of 2 (2^a)
for(int i = 1; i <= a; i++){
    pow2 *= 2;
    pow2 %= m;
}
// power of 3 (3^b)
for(int j = 1; j <= b; j++){
    pow3 *= 3;
    pow3 %= m;
}
```

Notice that this is still suboptimal - it is possible to calculate much larger powers by using [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

*Finally* you must note that the *last* product must be mod 1000000007 too, otherwise the result is larger than expected:

```
printf("%lld\n", i * j % m);
```